# Plotting 5 different timeseries datasets in the same plot with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, plot, time-series

currently I have 5 objects in a python script containing time series data, the objects have the same time length (24 hours)and the captured value is temperature in Celsius.

I would like to plot the 5 objects into one single plot with 5 different labels, what is the simplest way to do this with pandas??

thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just plot you data with pyplot and then put `plt.show()` at the end. Everything before the `plt.show()` will be in the same plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

plt.plot(data1, label="label1")
plt.plot(data2, label="label2")
...

plt.legend(loc="best")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Arne, originally I was looking for a pandas solution to this, but using pyplot worked, fast and easy, no hassle, thanks